# clang-format: don't break between string and << operator

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have the following line in my C++ code:

```
std::cout << "done" << "\n";
```

which clang-format breaks into

```
std::cout << "done"
          << "\n";
```

no matter what. I have edited every option that starts with "Break" or "Align":

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveMacros: 'false'
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'false'
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: 'false'
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: 'false'
AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign
AlignOperands:   DontAlign
AlignTrailingComments: 'false'

BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterComma
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakStringLiterals: false
```

How can I make it not do this? Version is 14.0.0

Comment: This particular case should just be `std::cout << "done\n";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clang-format erroneously always puts consecutive `<< "string"` onto separate lines. [This is a known bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44363), first reported in Feb 2020.

Your configuration works for for statements like:

```cpp
// This doesn't get split over multiple lines;
// it only happens if the column limit is exceeded.
int x = 1 << 2 << 3;
```

Normally, **only if** a line is too long:

- [BreakBeforeBinaryOperators](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakbeforebinaryoperators) controls whether the line is broken before/after operators.
- [AlignOperands](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignoperands) controls horizontal alignment of operators.

However, when a `<<` is followed by a string literal, clang-format will put it onto a separate line, no matter what.